# Multiselect list not showing selected items in c# mvc using linq2sql

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, multi-select, selectlistitem

I've tried many different ways to pass the selected items to the multiselect list with no luck.  Finally, I tried this, which I think should display all the items as selected and still nothing in the list is selected.

```
public MultiSelectList Companies { get; private set; }

Companies = MulitSelectList(subcontractRepository.SubcontractCompanies(Subcontract.subcontract_id), "Value", "Text");
```

in SubcontractRepository.cs:

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> SubcontractCompanies(Guid id)
{
     return c in db.companies
     select new SelectListItem
     {
          Text = c.company_name,
          Value = c.company_id.ToString(),
          Selected = true
     }
}
```

in View:

```
<p>
    <label for="Companies">Company:</label>
    <%= Html.ListBox("Companies", Model.Companies) %>
    <%= Html.ValidationMessage("Companies", "*") %>
</p>
```

Comment: What version of mvc you are using?
Does field name in view match Model.FieldName?

Comment: 1.0  The names are the same.  I see the list, it just doesn't have anything selected.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Discovered the issue here.  The MultiSelectList must have a different name from the ListBox.  Made that change and now both versions of the code work.

Answer (score 2):

MultiSelectList constructor has fourth parameter - selected items. Use it:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.multiselectlist.multiselectlist.aspx

Use this code:

```
public class SelectCompanyItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}

public IEnumerable<SelectCompanyItem> SubcontractCompanies(Guid id)
{
     return c in db.companies
     select new SelectCompanyItem
     {
          Name = c.company_name,
          Id = c.company_id
     }
}

var companiesList = subcontractRepository.SubcontractCompanies(Subcontract.subcontract_id);
Companies = new MultiSelectList(companiesList , "Id", "Name", companiesList.Select(a => a.Id));
```

Does it work?

Comment: That was the first way that I attempted to do it.  I could not get that to work either.  I was hoping that if I figured out what was wrong above, that I could discover what I was doing wrong.

Comment: So you did something wrong. Don't convert `c.company_id` to string. It is not needed.

Comment: I know I've done something wrong.  I am attempting to learn what.
When I do not have the .ToString() it complains "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Guid' to 'string'"

Comment: @RememberME : This code works for me. I have ListBox with all items selected.

Comment: No, nothing is selected for me.

Comment: @RememberME : View looks ok. Do you do the rest as I wrote in my response?

Comment: Yes, I just double checked and everything is exactly like it is in your code.

Comment: @LukLed - Thanks for the help.  I discovered the issue.  See my answer